# Setting specific lists to open codes in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a very big project with lots of .cs files a lot of them are connected to perform a certain function in the program.
my problem is that whenever I want to change the focus of my work from a functionality to another, I have to close most of the currently open files (some of them might be related to or needed for multiple functions) and open the codes I need one by one. it is mostly time-consuming since I have to go around looking for the thing I might need and open them.
Are there any ways to put the files related to a specific topic and just choose the lists to switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in `Visual Studio` to `Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets`. You can utilise that.
**[Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)**

> From the My Work page you can save and then restore not only your file
> changes and related work items, but also the position of your open
> windows, breakpoints, and other important cues.
>
> In Team Explorer, choose  Home, and then choose My Work. On the My
> Work page, choose Suspend & Shelve, and then type a description of the
> suspended work.
>
> When you are ready to resume the work, go the Suspended & Shelved Work
> section of the My Work page, select a set of suspended work, and
> choose Resume.
> [image]
> [image]

Note: it works with TFS 2018 | TFS 2017 | TFS 2015 | VS 2017 | VS 2015 | VS 2013

Another link reference to [Manage pending changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes)

Comment: Isn't this a type of version control system - when you Resume from a save shelveset then all of the files that were saved are restored to the version at the time of saving. If files are shared between "functionality" any edits to common files will be lost when Resuming.

Comment: *If files are shared between "functionality" any edits to common files will be lost when Resuming.* - yes, you are right, we need to create shelve-set (let say 'shelve1') for those common files, suspend the work and then unshelve the 'shelve1' to go ahead with another 'functionality'.

Comment: This seems like a very bad abuse of a version control system & easily result in OP having multiple versions of the same files in different shelvesets when the only requirement is to be able to open a group of files.

Comment: your point is completely valid in situations, but as OP has mentioned, *my problem is that whenever I want to change the focus of my work from a functionality to another, I have to close all currently open files and open the codes I need one by one. it is mostly time-consuming since I have to go around looking for the thing I might need and open them.* - this `Suspend current work` functionality seems to be helping with OP's expectations.

Comment: @Paritosh I appreciate the answer. but what PaulF said is actually true. some of the files are acting a rule in multiple functions. If suspending the work would save the files and show the updated files for other shelves then this is the answer. I'll edit the question to correct my mistake.

Comment: @Henjin: any common updated files would only be saved to your latest shelveset, restoring from a different shelveset would get the copy that was saved at that time (ie a version without your latest updates) - shelving files does not update copies on all shelves.